# How can I tell if a TFS project was setup using Scrum or Agile?

Tags: tfs

I'm assuming if I log into a project and there are User Stories then the project was created using the Agile template and if there are Product Backlog Items and Bugs then the project was created using the Scrum template.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Also if you see Requirements then project was created with CMMI template.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the workitem types to check for your process template.

CMMI is Requirement

Scrum is Prodcut backlog item

Agile is User Story